# Reading OneToMany conditionally

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I have 2 tables/entities: 'User' and 'Relation' (1:n) and need to read all users with only matching 'relation' with current user. The problem is in generated SQL there is *also* 'join' instead of 'left join'

User has field:

```
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
    public List<Relation> relation;
```

Entity 'Relation' has 2 references on User:

```
    @OneToOne(targetEntity = User.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    public User user;

    @OneToOne(targetEntity = User.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "other_id")
    public User other;
```

The code reading `User` using `JPA Specification` this way:

```
   (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
        root.join("relation", JoinType.LEFT);
        Predicate userPredicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("relation").get("user"), user);
        Predicate otherPredicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("relation").get("other"), root);
        return criteriaBuilder.and(userPredicate, otherPredicate);
   }
```

The result query is wrong: it has also 'join'.

```
    ...
    from
        users u1_0 
    left join
        relations r1_0 
            on u1_0.id=r1_0.user_id 
    join  <----------------------------
        relations r2_0 
            on u1_0.id=r2_0.user_id 
    where
        ...
```

So, the question is how to fix so that there is only a 'LEFT JOIN', not just 'JOIN' ?

Comment: `root.get("relation")` <- A simple get on a relation will create an inner join. YOu should be able to save the result of `root.join("relation", JoinType.LEFT);` in a variable and reuse that join.